# Service for emailing attachments to a web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, email

I want to allow users to upload images to my web app by emailing them from their phones, or email account.   Ii am using Rails 3.   Could anyone suggests any web services that allow this kind off functionality, or other libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that cloudmain does this: http://cloudmailin.com/

Comment: I think this might be exactly what I had in mind (and forgot existed).